# List manipulation and using STDIN

Tags: python-3.x, list, stdout, stdin

I am working on this example on internet and iam trying to understand the code.

the example says the sample input is

```
    12
    insert 0 5
    insert 1 10
    insert 0 6
    print 
    remove 6
    append 9
    append 1
    sort 
    print
    pop
    reverse
    print
```

and that by applying this code

```
L=[];
t=int(input());
for i in range(0,t):
    cmd=input().split();
    if cmd[0] == "insert":
        L.insert(int(cmd[1]),int(cmd[2]))
    elif cmd[0] == "append":
        L.append(int(cmd[1]))
    elif cmd[0] == "pop":
        L.pop();
    elif cmd[0] == "print":
        print L
    elif cmd[0] == "remove":
        L.remove(int(cmd[1]))
    elif cmd[0] == "sort":
        L.sort();
    else:
        L.reverse();
```

i should get an output similar to this:

Sample Output

```
[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

I have all ingredients and yet i am not able to figure this out. My problem is that i don't know how i should enter the sample input (i.e., in what format?) does it have to be entered as a list or as a string..i am really not sure. Please help

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code is working fine at my end.

Comment: the code works fine but how did you enter the input? did you just copy and paste the sample input without put brackets or parentheses?

Comment: I entered the input one by one.  I would recommend you to pass the message like `cmd = input("Enter input:").split()`

Comment: The input should be entered on `stdin`, the standart input. You have the possibility to run the code 'as is' in a console (run `python my_script.py`), and then to write the lines one by one on the console prompt; or to write the input in a file (say `my_input.txt`), and to run your python script as `python my_script_py < my_input.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ll do. What is the point of the for loop then 'for i in range(0,t):' ? is it to check the size of the individual input?

Comment: when i enter the input "insert 0 5"   i get an error saying                   
         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'insert 0 5' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what happens, let's have a look at the code piece by piece.
First, an empty list is declared. It will store all the values

```
L=[];
```

Then, the user is prompted to enter the size of the input, this value (a `string`) is converted (cast) into an integer (`int`).

```
t=int(input());
```

It could have been more explicit by adding some information for the user to read.

```
t=int(input('Please enter the size of your input\n'));
```

After that, the program will loop `t` times.

```
for i in range(0,t):
```

In this loop, the user is first prompted to enter an input (here a command). This input is splitted: the `split()` function transforms a `string` into a list of strings (which were separated by a space) called `cmd`.

```
    cmd=input().split();
```

Again, it could be more explicit.

```
    cmd=input('Please enter a command\n').split();
```

Now, we 'switch' (there is no switch in python, so it's a serie of 'if, else if, else if ...) on the command, and act accordingly.

```
    if cmd[0] == "insert":
        L.insert(int(cmd[1]),int(cmd[2]))
    elif cmd[0] == "append":
        L.append(int(cmd[1]))
    elif cmd[0] == "pop":
        L.pop();
    elif cmd[0] == "print":
        print L
    elif cmd[0] == "remove":
        L.remove(int(cmd[1]))
    elif cmd[0] == "sort":
        L.sort();
    else:
        L.reverse();
```

You can now see why your input starts with `12` on the first line , it is the number of lines below that your program should read, and that will be stored in `t`. If it is too small, for instance, `6`, your program will read only the 6 first commands. If it is too big, for instance `42`, your program will wait for more input, and stay in its loop. It will look like it is stuck while it acutally is only waiting for some input from `stdin`.

To answer your last comment about the error when your first input line is `insert 0 5`, it is the python interpreter trying to convert it into an integer, and store it in `t`. Since it cannot (`insert 0 5` is not a string representing an integer), it crashes.
You could catch this error with a `try .. except` construct like that

```
while True:
    try:
        t=int(input('Please enter the size of your input\n'));
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('You must input an integer! Try again.')
```

Comment: thank you so much. First enter the size of the input then enter the input. I was very far from guessing that it was the case. Not easy to guess for python beginners to be honest. This exercise is supposed to be for beginners. In other words, i need to enter 12 and enter one input at the time which in theory should result in the final "sample" output. I have tried to do that but i am not getting similar result as the sample output i must be going wrong somewhere. Again thank you so much again

Comment: So you understand now not only the way this program works, but also one of the 'Zen of Python' sentence: 'Explicit is better than implicit'.
Also, a way to see how your program behaves when you do not understand it, is to print the value of some variables (here you will want to print `L`) at various point in the program. That can help you to understand its behavior. It's not considered a good practice, but can be really helpful when you're starting with code.

Comment: Ah, and one last advice. This code is Python 2 code. Python 2 will not be maintained anymore very soon (end of this year), so I'd advice you to start learning Python 3 (it is very uncommon, but  python is not backward compatible). As a python beginner, you should not see any difference except the parenthesis after `print`, but you'll be sure to learn the 'right' version of the language.

Comment: got it thank you so much for your patience and effort. I am glad stackoverflow offers this platform where beginners and experts coders meet and share knowledge. Thank you sir!